# Problem fetching data from firebase there is some problem while generating get request to fetch images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Here, is the code that I am using to fetch data from the Firebase It shows that the images are not present in the database but I have triple-checked the images re-uploaded them, and checked again, and I still get the same error, it happens only when I want to fetch images, without them everything works.

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PlayerCard from '../Utils/playerCard';
import { Promise } from 'core-js'
import { showErrorToast } from '../Utils/tools';
import { CircularProgress } from '@mui/material';
import { firebase, playersCollection } from '../../firebase'

const TheTeam = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!players) {
      playersCollection
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          const players = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          }))
          let promises = [];

          players.forEach((player, index) => {
            promises.push(
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                firebase.storage().ref('players')
                  .child(player.image).getDownloadURL()
                  .then(url => {
                    players[index].url = url;
                    resolve()
                  }).catch(error => {
                    reject()
                  })
              })
            )
          });

          Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            setPlayers(players);
          })
        }).catch(error => {
          showErrorToast('Sorry try again later')
        }).finally(() => {
          setLoading(false)
        })
    }
  }, [players])

  const showPlayerByCategory = (category) => (
    players ?
      players.map((player, i) => {
        return player.position === category ?
          <div className="item" key={player.id}>
            <PlayerCard
              number={player.number}
              name={player.name}
              lastname={player.lastname}
              bck={player.url}
            />
          </div>
          : null
      })
      : null
  )

  return (
    <div className="the_team_container">
      {loading ?
        <div className="progress">
          <CircularProgress />
        </div>
        :
        <div>
          <div className="team_category_wrapper">
            <div className="title">Keepers</div>
            <div className="team_cards">
              {showPlayerByCategory('Keeper')}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="team_category_wrapper">
            <div className="title">Defence</div>
            <div className="team_cards">
              {showPlayerByCategory('Defence')}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="team_category_wrapper">
            <div className="title">Midfield</div>
            <div className="team_cards">
              {showPlayerByCategory('Midfield')}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="team_category_wrapper">
            <div className="title">Strikers</div>
            <div className="team_cards">
              {showPlayerByCategory('Striker')}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default TheTeam;
```

below are the firestore permissions if you need them:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 6, 12);
    }
  }
}
```

Also, this is how the stored data in the Firebase looks like:
and I checked the firebase Storage and the image is present there.
[image]

What do need to change?
What am I doing wrong?